# AWS java web server

Tags: java, http, amazon-web-services, client

I am trying to build a java server using AWS on an EC2 server on tomact. Why i am building is for a game i am making in unity. This will not be a real time game where I need a constant connection between clients. That being said I have a rough idea of what I think i need.

What I have:

I have installed ecplise with the aws sdk and that is about it.

What I think i need:

I a REST style server so I can make http calls. I have been told this is very simple to do because the data i need to transfer wont be needed to make in real time just pull when i need it to be pulled by the client. I have also seen stuff about jersey api and stuff but I am not sure I need that.

Can someone point me in some good direction of tutorials, I have looked but I am still lost on what I need to be doing exactly. I essentially need a java server to run on a AWS tomact server and make http calls between an iphone client and a server. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your question about the AWS services related to spinning up webservers, the programmatic manipulation of AWS resources with the java SDK, or something else? Could you clarify?

Comment: It is the manipulation of the java code. I have already have a server on AWS and I need it to run a java web application that could accept (what i think and have been told) http calls from a client (aka an iphone) i would just need the server some integers and strings and have the server give a response. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Development: 
You should prefer Spring REST for server http calls. If you are new for Spring framework then you can go with **JSP web server**.

Create Java Web Application from eclipse new project tab.
You can response to clients as per their request and needs.
This tutorial will help you:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/

---

Deployment:
You can use **aws elastic beanstalk** for easy deployment using eclipse.

Just follow Getting started with java from aws site:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html